# how to add JQuery focusin event properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on Google Apps Script with JQuery. I want to make `focusin` event work.

```
    var kojiNameElem = $("#koji_"+koji_id).find(".kojiName");

    var kojiNameId = kojiNameElem .attr("id");
    console.log("kojiNameId="+kojiNameId);//kojiNameId=koji-name-1

    $(kojiNameElem).on("focusin", function(e) {
    console.log("focusin");
    $(e.target).removeClass("bg-danger");
  }, false);

    console.log("done");//done
```

It seems that the program is ok till I can get the element: `var kojiNameId = kojiNameElem .attr("id");`. and besides, it goes till the end properly: `console.log("done");`. So, I think the part I add the event has something wrong. Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. The focusin event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, gains focus. This is distinct from the focus event in that it supports detecting the focus event on parent elements

```
$(kojiNameElem).focusin(function() {
    console.log("focusin");
});
```

Comment: thank you! it worked. I found the real cause of this problem is adding false to the 2nd parameter of $(...).on(). So, it also works with my original code without the false in the 2nd parameter.